# Enabling Session State in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, session-state, sharepoint-2010, session-variables

I have a web service built for SharePoint 2007 that I am trying to port to SharePoint 2010.  This web service is dependent on session state to function properly, but so far, I have been enable to get session state to work at all in SharePoint 2010.  This web service runs as its own web application under t
he `/_vti_bin` virtual directory.  I have tried all of the following with no luck:

- Ensured the "State Service" service application is running.
- Added the `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule` http module to my application's web.config file.
- Added the `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule` http module to my SharePoint root web.config file.
- Added `<pages enableSessionState="true" />` to my application's web.config file.
- Added `<pages enableSessionState="true" />` to my root web.config file.

Additional Environment info:

- Visual Studio 2008 - SP1
- .NET 3.5 - SP1
- SharePoint 2010 - RC
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- ASMX web service (not WCF)

Had anyone had any luck getting a web application *or* web service to use session state in SharePoint 2010 yet?

Thanks!

Steve

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've already answered this yourself somewhere else on the interweb. :)

```xml
<httpModules> 
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" /> 
</httpModules>
```

THEN, you must go into your web application and add the same session state module to the IIS7 managed pipeline.

1. Open IIS 7 manager, and find your web application.
2. Double click "Modules" in the IIS section.
3. Click "Add Managed Module..." on the right hand pane.
4. In the Add Managed Module dialog, enter `"SessionState"` or something like that for the name, and choose the following item from the dropdown:

   > System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

After that, session state should be enabled for your web app/web service!

Comment: You're right about that.  I figured it out several days later, I updated the MSDN forum since the question seemed to generate interest there.

Comment: Seems like the httpModules element is empty in SP 2010, does anyone know why?

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me without the Web.Config change - `<httpModules/>` is still empty, I just added the IIS Module.

Comment: HI i have done above things in my site but it doesnt work for me. is it possible in sharepoint foundation 2010 version?

Answer (score 6):

You may need to turn on the Session State Service.  Use the PowerShell cmdlet Enable-SPSessionStateService.  This will create a Session State database and start the service in SharePoint 2010.

Reference information:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890113.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The best link I have seen on this is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Joshua's solution helped point me in the right direction but I had to make some variations for my scenario - an ASP.NET 3.5 Web Site deployed to the _layouts folder.

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. changed the `<pages>` tag in the web.config for the Web Site to `<pages enableSessionState="true" />`
2. Added the **System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule** module at the Sharepoint website level (not the entire IIS level - that'll break the Central Administration, I tried :( ) as per @Joshua's solution. If you're deploying a Web Application instead of a Web Site, you'll want to add it at your Web Application level.

Adding the SessionState HTTPModule below to the web.config didn't seem to have an effect for me, probably because I was riding on Sharepoint's web.config as my project was a Web Site and not a Web Application. Not too clear on this issue.

```
<httpModules> 
    <add name = "Session" type = "System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" /> 
</httpModules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like below:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllrequests>
   <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
 </modules>
```

modules is an xml tag. I don't know why, this post is not taking xml tags..

Thanks

Carol